# TinyMCE won't wrap html comments in a <p>

Tags: tinymce, modx

...and this is correct behavior but where is this file with this setting in TinyMCE 3.4.7 (in modx Revolution 2.2.6 it's TinyMCE 4.3.3)?
Is it possible to add some other exceptions? For example if I want everything be wrapped in p except img, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure what is valid and what is not. For this check the tinymce configuration parameters valid_elements, valid_children and extended_valid_elements.